# OOP Terminology: "Container" & "Collection"

Tags: java, c++, oop, terminology

Is the C++ term "Container" simply synonymous with the Java term "Collection" ?

Comment: +1 was thinking about this just yesterday

Comment: A collection implies the possibility of multiple elements, whereas e.g., `std::any`, `std::function`, `std::optional`, etc. contain at most one element. So all collections are containers but not all containers are collections imho.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

Though, if I may speculate here, C++ term *container* better emphasizes ownership of contained items, as opposed to Java's *collection*, where there is no explicit memory ownership (due to garbage collection).

Items in a C++ container are destroyed when a container is destroyed (hence items are *contained* or owned), in Java items may continue to exist if a collection itself is garbage collected.

Comment: Though if the container only contains pointers, then the objects themselves don't get destroyed!

Comment: @hasen in that case the elements are the pointers (not the pointees). The pointers are contained within the container, and will be (trivially) destructed and deallocated by the container.

Answer (score 6):

[Container (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(data_structure))
[Collection (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collection_(computing))

If I understand correctly - usualy this difference is not significant.

When we talk about group of objects we say "collection of objects".
If we talk about data structure which contain group of objects we say container.

e.g.: std::vector< int > - collection of ints or container vector which contain ints.